# Relocate and duplicate a string in R

Tags: r

I aim to relocate words and copy&paste them in certain pattern.

```
a = 'blahblah (Peter|Sally|Tom)'
b = 'word (apple|grape|tomato) vocabulary (rice|mice|lice)'
c = 'people person (you|me|us) do not know how (it|them) works'
```

I can relocate a string placed before '(' by using `gsub`

```
gsub('\\s*(\\S+)\\s*\\(', '(\\1 ', a)
```

With the function, I can make string sets below.

```
a
[1]'(blahblah Peter|Sally|Tom)'
b
[1]'(word apple|grape|tomato) (vocabulary rice|mice|lice)'
c
[1]'people (person you|me|us) do not know (how it|them) works'
```

However, I have no idea how to copy `'\\1'` and paste it after `'|'` like this

```
a
[1]'(blahblah Peter|blahblah Sally|blahblah Tom)'
b
[1]'(word apple|word grape|word tomato) (vocabulary rice|vocabulary mice|vocabulary lice)'
c
[1]'people (person you|person me|person us) do not know (how it|how them) works'
```

Is there any way to make this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `strsplit`

```
sapply(strsplit(a, "[| ]|\\(|\\)"), function(x) {
        x1 <- x[nzchar(x)]
        paste0("(", paste(x1[1], x1[-1], collapse="|"), ")")})
#[1] "(blahblah Peter|blahblah Sally|blahblah Tom)"
```

For multiple cases

```
paste(sapply(strsplit(b, "(?<=\\))\\s+", perl = TRUE)[[1]],
      function(x) sapply(strsplit(x,  "[| ]|\\(|\\)"), function(y) { 
          x1 <- y[nzchar(y)]
        paste0("(", paste(x1[1], x1[-1], collapse="|"), ")") })), collapse=' ')
#[1] "(word apple|word grape|word tomato) (vocabulary rice|vocabulary mice|vocabulary lice)"
```

---

Another option is `str_extract`

```
library(stringr)
m1 <- matrix(str_extract_all(b, "\\w+")[[1]], ncol=2)
do.call(sprintf, c(do.call(paste, c(as.data.frame(matrix(paste(m1[1,][col(m1[-1,])],
    m1[-1,]), nrow=2, byrow=TRUE)), sep="|")), list(fmt = "(%s) (%s)")))
#[1] "(word apple|word grape|word tomato) (vocabulary rice|vocabulary mice|vocabulary lice)"
```

#### Update

Based on the new pattern showed in the OP's post, we create a more general approach

```
funPaste <- function(str1){
     v1 <- strsplit(str1, "\\s+")[[1]]
     i1 <- grep("\\(", v1)
     v1[i1] <- mapply(function(x,y) paste0("(", paste(x, y, collapse="|"), ")"),
                    v1[i1-1], str_extract_all(v1[i1], "\\w+"))
     paste(v1[-(i1-1)], collapse=" ")
}

funPaste(a)
#[1] "(blahblah Peter|blahblah Sally|blahblah Tom)"
funPaste(b)
#[1] "(word apple|word grape|word tomato) (vocabulary rice|vocabulary mice|vocabulary lice)"
funPaste(c)
#[1] "people (person you|person me|person us) do not know (how it|how them) works"
```

#### Update2

We can also make use of `gsubfn`

```
library(gsubfn)
funPaste2 <- function(str1){
    gsubfn("(\\w+)\\s+[(]([^)]+)[)]", function(x,y) 
   paste0("(", paste(x, unlist(strsplit(y, "[|]")), collapse="|"), ")"), str1)
 }

funPaste2(c(a, b, c))
#[1] "(blahblah Peter|blahblah Sally|blahblah Tom)"                                         
#[2] "(word apple|word grape|word tomato) (vocabulary rice|vocabulary mice|vocabulary lice)"
#[3] "people (person you|person me|person us) do not know (how it|how them) works"
```

Comment: @Rcoding Because the pattern is different in the second example

Comment: can you tell me the meaning of "(?<=\\))\\s+" and "[| ]|\\(|\\)" ?

Comment: @Rcoding It means one or more space (`\\s+`) after a closing parentheses (`\\)` used as a regex lookaround.  In the second case, we are matching a `|` or spaces (`[| ]`) or (`|`) opening parenetheses (`\\(`) or `|` or closing (`\\)`)

Comment: @Rcoding Updated the pst

Comment: @Rcoding THe new function `funPaste` works in all the cases you showed

Comment: @Rcoding Updated with a more compact option

Answer (score 1):

another method: (with as less regex as possible) - since I don't know much :)

```
c=unlist(strsplit(b, " "))[c(T,F)] # extract all the single words 
# c
# [1] "blahblah"
# [1] "word"       "vocabulary" 
d=unlist(strsplit)(b, " ")[c(F,T)] # extract the grouped words
#  d
# [1] "(Peter|Sally|Tom)"
# [1] "(apple|grape|tomato)" "(rice|mice|lice)"        

# now iterate through each 'd', split it on `|` and then clear it on `()` this output is then pasted with contents of 'c'
sapply(seq_along(d), function(x) paste("(", paste(c[x],gsub("(\\(|\\))", "",unlist(strsplit(d[x], "\\|"))), 
                                              collapse = "|"),")"))

# [1] "( blahblah Peter|blahblah Sally|blahblah Tom )"
# [1] "( word apple|word grape|word tomato )"  "( vocabulary rice|vocabulary mice|vocabulary lice )"
```